# how to select a attribute name (fn:local-name() with xquery

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, xquery

This query `select @x.query('data(realm/roles/role[4]/@*[2])')`  against this  xml(

```
<realm name="ACP" context="Expresslane">
  <roles>
    <role name="Administrator" />
    <role name="elUser" />
    <role name="ElAdministrator" />
    <role name="regionalManager" justtest="aaa">
      <constraints>
        <constraint name="CustomerList" mode="Select">
          select * from BaanEl.com010nnn where t$cuno in(select * from baanEl.ftPriceListCustomers(&lt;%=comno%&gt;,&lt;%cpls%&gt;))
        </constraint>
      </constraints>
    </role>
    <role name="Rep" />
    <role name="DiscountAdministrator" />
    <role name="LoginAdmin">
      <realm url="http://localhost/PriceWorx_Sandbox/Default.aspx#tabs-2" visible="true" enabled="true" />
    </role>
  </roles>
  <rolegroups>
    <rolegroup name="Administrators">
      <member name="Administrator" />
      <memeber name="elUser" />
      <member name="elAdministrator" />
      <member name="regionalManagee" />
      <member name="Rep" />
      <member name="DiscountAdministrator" />
      <member name="LoginAdmin" />
    </rolegroup>
  </rolegroups>
</realm
```

> )
>    returns proper attribute value..

how do I get the name (local-name) of the same attribute ?

Comment: You could use `realm/roles/role[4]/@*[2]/local-name(.)`. **But do not rely in attributes' `position()`**: XML parsers do not have to preserve source order.

Comment: @Alejandro: It wouldnt work, throws XQuery [query()]: 'local-name()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'attribute(*,xdt:untypedAtomic) *'

Comment: It works on Saxon, Altova and XQSharp. This `local-name(/realm/roles/role[4]/@*[2])` won't work if there is going to select more than one attribute (more than one `roles` with a fourth `role` child having two attributes, i.e.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
  name = @x.query('local-name((realm/roles/role[4]/@*[2])[1])')
, val  = @x.query('data(realm/roles/role[4]/@*[2])')

/* -- OUTPUT
 name      val
 justtest  aaa
*/
```